# Grafana: DeSelect legend (not Disable) as config

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-templating, grafana-api

There is Grafana panel for memory for kubernetes Deployment + Pod metrics. In the below image, there is 4 graphs -

1. Yellow - `Total` (overall) memory used by Deployment
2. Green - `Average` memory used per pod in Deployment
3. (& 4.) Blue & Red - Memory used by individual pod

[image]

If we notice the metrics, `Total` memory metrics (Deployment) is overshadowing other's memory metrics. As a resultant, we de-selected `Total` legend manually (shown in below image no metrics for Total) by pressing CTRL+Click.  After doing this, other's metrics can be seen easily.

So as a solutions. we are looking for **DE-SELECTING** `Total` legend in panel configuration and this will served as DEFAULT behavior that can enabled SELECTION (manually) whenever required.

[image]

**Note:** Please do not suggest to make another panel for Deployment's metrics. We want to keep it all together to make comparable at single place.

Comment: I don't think described behavior is achievable in vanilla Grafana. Would you consider different Y scale for Total?